# How to paste multiple table ranges into Outlook body using Word Editor (As Images)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I can paste one excel range into outlook (as an image) with no issue but when it comes to pasting multiple ranges into the body of outlook (on separate lines) I run into formatting issues.

I am trying to paste one range, insert a "line break", then paste another range, and so-on.  I've tried various methods of separating the images but nothing is working.  The images paste successfully but only on one line, which makes everything out of alignment.

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.document
    Dim strGreeting As String

    strGreeting = "Dear Someone," & vbNewLine

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .display

        .To = "Someone@tester.com"
        .Subject = "Report"

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor

        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strGreeting


        ' This is where I am having problems:
        ' The tables are pasting into the document out of order (not a huge problem) but...
        ' the images paste on ONE single line, I need the images to paste on a new line so they
        ' format vertically along the body of the email.

        'Range #1 one to copy/paste into outlook body
        Range("W2:AB40").Copy
        wdDoc.Range(Len(strGreeting) & vbCrLf, Len(strGreeting)).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        'Range #2 one to copy/paste into outlook body
        Range("E2:I26").Copy
        wdDoc.Range(Len(strGreeting) & vbCrLf, Len(strGreeting)).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        'Range #3 one to copy/paste into outlook body
        Range("N38:V50").Copy
        wdDoc.Range(Len(strGreeting) & vbCrLf, Len(strGreeting)).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        'Range #4 one to copy/paste into outlook body
        If shtWash.Range("SHIFT_GROUP") = "DAYS" Then
            Range("N2:V18").Copy
        Else
            Range("N2:V36").Copy
        End If
        wdDoc.Range(Len(strGreeting) & vbCrLf, Len(strGreeting)).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        'Range #5 one to copy/paste into outlook body
        Range("E28:I34").Copy
        wdDoc.Range(Len(strGreeting) & vbCrLf, Len(strGreeting)).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim strGreeting As String

    strGreeting = "Dear Someone," & vbNewLine

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olEmail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .display

        .To = "Someone@tester.com"
        .Subject = "Report"

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor

        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strGreeting

        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf

        Range("A1:D10").Copy
        PasteAtEnd wdDoc

        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        Range("A12:D20").Copy
        PasteAtEnd wdDoc

    End With

End Sub

'paste from clipboard to the end of the document
Sub PasteAtEnd(doc As Word.Document)
    With doc
        .Content.Select
        .Application.Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
        .Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Tim.  Your method is working great, is there any way to modify your code to keep the signature at the bottom of the outlook message?  That was an added issue I was experiencing with mine as well as your code.

Comment: I'm sure that's possible but I don't have outlook here to test with.

Comment: @Skynet Look at and test the `Selection.MoveUp`, and `Selection.MoveEnd` methods of the Word object model. One or both of those should help you change where the content is being pasted.